# How much sample is enough?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am aware that my question is basic. But I have no background in statistics, know no terminology, and thus need your help. It might be standard, and answer might be found in textbook. If this is the case, please help point out where to look for a treatment. Thank you in advance!

#### Set up

$N$ balls are in a pool, either red or blue. $PN$ of them are red, and $(1-P)N$ of them are blue. Here, $N$ and $P$ are fixed, and $N$ is very large. I aim to estimate $P$ by sampling $n$ balls from it.

In a random sampling of $n$ balls, the probability of $pn$ of them being red (so $(1-p)n$ of them are blue) is

$$
F(N,P;n,p) = \frac{{PN\choose pn}{(1-P)N\choose (1-p)n}}{N\choose n}
$$

**My main goal is to understand this function as a "continuous" one (continuous because $N$ is very large).**

Consider $n$ fixed for a moment, the only variable being $p$. I imagine if $n$ is "large enough", then $F$ should peak at $p=P$.

#### Question

**1.** How to prove this? I tried to take the derivative of $F$ in $p$, but they are discrete functions.. I'm not sure if it is justified to take the derivatives, with the factorials modeled by $\Gamma$-functions.

**2.** Now let $n\to N$, I imagine the distribution should "converge" to zero, except at $p=P$. How to prove this? And how to estimate how fast it converges?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to prove the law of large numbers. You can say that the random variable $\xi$ is equal to 1 if the ball is red and 0 otherwise and then your question is exactly that law: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\xi _i}{n}=E \xi$. The limit here is not exactly that one we're used to ($\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists N ...$), unfortunately I don't know what is this limit called in English, but the general point is the same — if we go further and further the probability that we go away too far from this value is equal to 0. Although I can't remember right now how to prove it, it should be pretty easy to find out now that your know its name — it's a very well-known and well-researched law

Comment: Good to know! Yes this does answer the second question. But I'd also like to understand the situation before the limit (question 1).

Comment: I think I didn't really get what exactly do you want to prove the first time. As I see it now you want to prove that if n is large then probability to take out exactly $pn$ reds is the highest of any other options. I think it's very similar to another very important theorem - central limit theorem. It states that if you take a lot of identical independent random variables, calculate their average (sum up and divide by n) subtract their expectation and then divide this hole thing by their dispersion over $\sqrt n$   then this converges to standart normal distribution. Not exactly this but close